# Image not loading in React Native when I use require but loads when I load from URL

Tags: image, react-native

When I try to load an image by using require, the image does not load but when I load the same image from a URL, the image loads. Here is the snippet of code that I am calling the image from

```
class Home extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        noSpacer={true}
        noScroll={true}
        style={styles.container}
        showVerticalSCrollIndicator = {false}
        showHorizontalScrollIndicator = {false}
      >
          {this.state.loading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator
            style={[styles.centering, styles.gray]}
            color="#5d38aa"
            size="large"
          />
        ) : (
          <div>
            <Header title={this.state.user.name} />
            <div id='image'>
              <Image
                source={require('./arrow.png')}
                style={styles.image}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

The image is loaded here

```
<Image
  source={require('./arrow.png')}
  style={styles.image}
/>
```

Comment: Are you sure the relative path to image ```'./arrow.png'``` is correct?

Comment: Yes the relative path to the image is correct. I tried and putting it in an assets folder './assets/arrow.png' but it still didn't work. I tried .jpg pictures also and it still wouldn't work as well

Comment: If possible, post it on GitHub, will look into it. If the path is correct then it should display unless you have not set the height and width, but it seems you have declared it in ```styles.image```

Comment: Here's the GitHub link https://github.com/nimbusdin/stackreactnative . Thank you for your help!

Comment: I tried your repo, it seems to work fine. There is no visible error in the ```Image``` component. While checking the repo, I have committed ```sanityClient``` and ```User``` component.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you give the right path to your image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the source as an object:

<Image source={{ uri: 'something.jpg' }} />

But what you have should work, check your path.

Answer (score 0):

There were few errors here and there, I think you were trying to port ReactJS code to RN and not surprisingly there were few slip-ups like you used `div` instead and `View` and small things like that, also `boxShadow` was not working so I removed that.

After a few tweaks code is working and images are loading.

As I stated earlier, I have omitted the `User` component and `sanityClient`, you can implement them later.

Here is the working `home.js` after changes.

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  ScrollView,
  ActivityIndicator,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  ImageBackground,
  View,
} from "react-native";
// import UserList from "./user-list";
import Header from "./header";
// import sanityClient from "";
// import BackButton from "./back-button";
// import User from "./user";
// import {Asset} from 'expo-asset';

// const imageURI = Asset.fromModule(require('./arrow.png')).uri;

// const image = require("./assets/aoeu.jpg");

class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: {},
    loading: true,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // TODO: get users
    this.getUser();
  }

  async getUser() {
    // sanityClient
    //   .fetch(
    //     `*[ _type == "user" && emailAddress.current == "dwight@viamaven.com"]`
    //   )
    //   .then((data) => {
    //     console.log(data);
    //     this.setState({ user: data[0], loading: false });
    //     console.log(this.state.user);
    //   })
    //   .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    // const res = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20");
    // const { results} = await res.json();
    // // console.log(results)
    // this.setState({users: [...results], loading: false});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        noSpacer={true}
        noScroll={true}
        style={styles.container}
        showVerticalSCrollIndicator={false}
        showHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      >
        {!this.state.loading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator
            style={[styles.centering, styles.gray]}
            color="#5d38aa"
            size="large"
          />
        ) : (
          <View>
            <Header title={"Spidy"} />
            <View id="image">
              <Image source={require("./arrow.png")} style={styles.image} />
            </View>
            {/* <User /> */}
          </View>
        )}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    width: 375,
    height: 812,
    // top: '50px',
  },
  centering: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: 8,
    height: "100vh",
  },
  image: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    marginRight: 20,
    // boxShadow: "0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)",
    // boxShadow: "10px 10px 17px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)",
  },
});

export default Home;
```

Zip file containing all the changes: [src](https://github.com/TheKetan2/stackoverflow_answers/blob/master/src.zip!)

Output:

[image]